# Determine type of compression used in string

Tags: encryption, compression

Bit of an odd one. I'm trying to interpret the data an appliance connected to my WiFi network is sending in response to my request for its status. I requested some information as a HTTP request, and the XML response returned `data=Hf+vEwAATAgyAAA4BgsMAAACAAAAAAAATAAAUHc=`

So the data I want to decode is

```
Hf+vEwAATAgyAAA4BgsMAAACAAAAAAAATAAAUHc=
```

My question is, is this encrypted, compressed? It looks like compression to me, but I am unable to figure out what type it is.

Comment: That's Base64-encoded

Comment: So the data is 'L28LPw' ?

Comment: Those are just the bytes in the data that happen to be printable characters. See my answer for the full binary contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not compressed. It is [Base64 encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). Decoded you get, in hex:

```
1d ff af 13 00 00 4c 08 32 00 00 38 06 0b 0c 00
00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 4c 00 00 50 77
```

The decoded form is not compressed either, given the long strings of zeros. Nor is it encrypted, for the same reason. Well-compressed data will, at least at first blush, appear to be random data. Well-encrypted data is indistinguishable from random data.

Comment: This is bang on. I figured out i had to change it into hex, and have now managed to tweak around with the different settings to determine what each hex code relates to. Thank you.